# Read file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying simply read file in Custom View, but every time is my output Null. 
There is my code:

```
            try
            {
                    InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("text.txt");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    String st = "";
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((st=br.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                            sb.append(st);
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "Text: " + st);
                    br.close();

            }catch (IOException e)
            {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e);
            }
```

I have file "text.txt" with text in folder app/src/main/assets. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is in line  Log.d(TAG, "Text: " + st);

you are printing the value of st which becomes  null after loop completion as you describe in condition of while

you are actually storing you result in  Stringbuilder variable sb

So print this variable

Log.d(TAG, "Text: " + sb.toString);